# How to initialize a javascript slider only on certain web pages

Tags: javascript, html, swiper.js

I have a website with several pages. there is a Swiper slider on the homepage. all pages have a main.js file where the slider is initialized. how do I make sure that the other pages don't get an error in the console?
Error:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: Swiper is not defined`

Comment: 1st read [ask] and [mcve], then try to chek if the element for Swiper exist

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the [Swiper API](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#initialize-swiper), you can see that it uses a class called Swiper to initialize the slider.

Since you just want to validate if the Swiper class is present in your page, you can simple test it's type:

```js
if (typeof Swiper != undefined) {
   const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper');
}
```

Comment: great solution! thanks